# Вопрос о наследовании

Tags: java-ee, java

Добрый вечер, уважаемые форумчане.
Возник вопрос по наследованию.

Имеется интерфейс и две имплементации этого интерфейса. Допустим, классы A и B. При инициализации класса A и класса B необходимо присвоить классу A класс B. Вопрос, собственно, в том, как это сделать? При попытке такое провернуть вполне ожидаемо, что java выкидывает `Exeption java.lang.ClassCastException` с описанием `cannot be cast to`.

Вот пример кода:

```
public interface Session {
public String getName();
public void setName(String name);
}

public class Websocket implements Session {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}

public class CWebsocket implements Session {
private Integer id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}

public class Test {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Websocket websocket =  new Websocket();
    websocket.setName("test");

    CWebsocket cWebsocket = (CWebsocket) websocket;
    System.out.println(cWebsocket.getName());
}
}
```

Заранее большое спасибо за внимание к проблеме.

Comment: И как вы себе это представляете и для чего?

Comment: Вопрос не стоит, для чего это делать, вопрос стоит, как это делать. ))

Comment: @ulcigor:

> присвоить классу A класс B

Это как, простите? Каков должен быть видимый эффект этого?

Comment: @ulcigor  а вы не передергивайте. Лично у меня создалось ощущение, что вы слабо себе представляете, что делаете. У вас две реализации интерфейса (одна спецификация), а вы хотите объявить одну реализацию, присвоить ей другую реализацию. Но, извольте, где логика?
Есть фигура круг, есть фигура квадрат. Круг != квадрат. Круг - фигура, квадрат - фигура. Я уж не знаю, как еще вам это объяснить. Вы не можете сделать подмену.

Comment: Ну, как минимум это чистой воды полиморфизм.  
Есть супер класс, есть класс наследник, супер клас может реализовать наследника, но вот наоборот, в этом, собственно, и вопрос.

Comment: @smackmychi 
Суть в том, что есть интерфейс (предположим круг), который является базой для классов, потому если я использую интерфейс круг, то квадрат у меня никак не получится (зависит от реализации).

Comment: @ulcigor еще раз почитайте и попробуйте понять. У вас две фигуры. Фигура - это их общий интерфейс. Есть две реализации круг и квадрат. Дак вот у вас в коде так и получается.

    интерфейс Фигура{...};
  
    класс Круг реализует интерфейс Фигура{...};
  
    класс Квадрат реализует интерфейс Фигура{...};
  
    Квадрат квадрат = (Квадрат) новый объект класса Круг;  //PROFIT...  
  

Ничего не смущает? Себя услышьте хоть раз - встанет на свои места все.

Comment: @smackmychi я же говорю, зависит от реализации, мне интерфейс нужен только для реализации кругов, квадрат меня вообще не интересует, соответственно реализующие классы выполняют одну и туже функцию (приблизительно).

Comment: @smackmychi давайте, чтобы не разводить спама, я просто объясню словами, что нужно.
Мне нужно классу наследнику присвоить класс родителя, которые по своей сути выполняют одну и туже функцию, за исключением некоторых модификаций. Я понимаю, что стандартными средствами полиморфизма этого не сделать, но, возможно, есть другой путь, допустим, реализация через рефлексию или что-то подобное. Я этого не знаю, потому и задал этот вопрос.

Comment: @ulcigor, зачем это вам? Если нужно преобразовать класс A к классу B, то создайте отдельный метод, который и будет этим заниматься.
Да, и у вас в примере класс CWebsocket не реализует интерфейс Session.

Answer (score 4):

Минутка словоблудия и отвлеченных рассуждений.

Понятие интерфейса в ООП не предполагает, что два класса, его реализующих, должны быть взаимозаменяемы. Смысл интерфейса в том, что классы, его реализующие, **могут выполнять одинаковые действия**. То есть это не означает, что один такой класс может быть заменен другим. Это означает, что поведение одного класса может быть заменено поведением другого. Вроде бы разница невелика, но она на само деле она существенна. Скажем, Человек может ходить (реализует соответствующий интерфейс), но и Часы тоже могуть ходить (тоже реализуют интерфейс). То есть и Человек и Часы могут выполнять одинаковое действие (хоть и совершенно разными способами), однако нельзя сказать, что объект класса Человек может быть заменен экземпляром класса Часы - между ними нет ничего общего, роме того, что они могут выполнять одно действие двумя разными способами. То есть ваше предположение о том, что две разные реализации одного интерфейса могут "присваиваться" друг другу, изначально неверно

Comment: Какая толстая демагогия ("ходить"). Ходить - функционировать и ходить - перемещаться относятся к разным "интерфейсам". Давайте еще и рыбаков сюда приплетем, которые в море как часы ходят.

Comment: "толстая демагогия" была приплетена как раз-таки не случайно, а именно для того, чтобы продемонстрировать, что две реализации одного интерфейса не обязаны  быть (и не являются) взаимозаменяемыми. Именно это самое отсутствие общего между двумя сущностями и призвано здесь подчеркнуть ту мысль, что не нужно пытаться запихивать две реализации интерфейса под общий знаменатель - цель интерфейсов в обеспечении схожего поведения, а не в обеспечении взаимозаменяемости сущностей

Comment: Забавно, ибо автор прямой речи не понимает, не то, что уж демагогию.

Comment: пардон, вы чего так на автора-вопроса-то то взъелись? Прям как будто он вас обидел чем-то

Comment: @DreamChild я лишь констатировал факт.